# Edit an app SharedPreferences

Tags: android

I want to edit the SharedPreferences of my app from the command line.

I tried:

```
adb shell 
vi /data/data/com.app/shared.../shard..xml
```

But vi is not installed, nano is also not installed.

So i tried pulling the file, but no permission.

Any solution?

Comment: no its not duplicated and it doesnt solve my issue\

Comment: There are multiple answers on that question, including mine, that show how to get data from internal storage -- such as `ShardPreferences` -- and copy that out to a development machine. This is what you claim to want to do ("So i tried pulling the file, but no permission"). You are welcome to edit your question to provide more details of why those solutions do not work.

Comment: nvm i figured it out, ty